# Is there a way to force a javascript element to redefine itself based on how it was originally defined?

Tags: javascript, typescript, data-binding

I was playing around with objects and constructors and stuff like that, and I was wondering if there was a way to bind a value to a variable based on how it was originally defined. I have the following code:

**typescript**

```js
let cr = "create",
  ap = "apply",
  $this = {
    set: (prop, value) => {
      this[prop] = value;
    }
  };
function creator() {
  this.$ = (array: Object[]) => {
    array.forEach((kp: Object) => {
      let key = Object.keys(kp)[0];
      let val = kp[Object.keys(kp)];
      $this[key] = val;
      creator.create(key, { value: val });
    });
  };
  this.apply = (...objects: Object[]) => {
    objects.forEach((obj: Object) => {
      creator.call(obj);
    });
  };
}
function create(obj) {
  function createValues(arr) {
    let instance: Object = new obj();
    let vals: any[] = [];
    arr.forEach(name => {
      vals.push(instance[name]);
    });
    return vals;
  }
  let names: string[] = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new obj());
  let values: string[] = createValues(names);
  return combineArrays(names, values);
}
function combineArrays(arr1, arr2): { $?: any } { // the question mark removes an IDE error
  let newObj: Object = {};
  arr1.forEach(prop => {
    newObj[prop] = arr2[arr1.indexOf(prop)];
  });
  return newObj;
}
Object.prototype.create = function(prop, options) {
  return Object.defineProperty(this, prop, options);
};
create(creator).$([
  { hi: "hi" }, 
  { bye: $this["hi"] } // this is the important stuff
]);
```

I was wondering if there is a way, inside the `set` function of the `$this` variable, to detect how it is *being* set and therefore determine if that value has changed and so it's value should to, if that makes any sense? Let's say you had this:

```js
let $this = {
  set: function(prop, value) {
    this[prop] = value;
  } 
}
let name = 'Ezra';
$this['name'] = name;
// then :
name = 'Bob';
// change $this.name too, so then:
console.log($this.name);
// >> 'Bob'
```

I believe this is called Data-Binding but I am unsure how to do it without creating endless numbers of proxies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is not really "data-binding" but [pass-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value). In your example you expect an update to `name` to be reflected in `$this['name']`. That would only be possible if you were passing a *reference* (or a *pointer*) to the variable.

However, in this case the variable is a `string`, and strings in JavaScript are [immutable](https://www.sitepoint.com/immutability-javascript/):

> no string methods change the string they operate on, they all return new strings. The reason is that strings are immutable – they cannot change, we can only ever make new strings.

So, going step-by-step through your example:

This creates a new string named 'Ezra', and assigns a variable called `name` to reference that string.

```
let name = 'Ezra';
```

This creates (or sets) a property in `$this` called `'name'` that references the string in `name` (which is `'Ezra'`).

```
$this['name'] = name;
```

This creates a new string called `'Bob'` and stores it in the variable called `name`. The variable already exists. This does not *mutate* the value that was previously held in there. Instead, `name` is being updated to point to a new reference.

```
// then :
name = 'Bob';
```

However, if you were to pass an *object*, you'll notice that you can actually mutate it. This is because objects are passed-by-reference and you can *mutate the value at that reference*.

For example:

```
// Create a new value that stores an object, with a property 'firstName'
let name = { firstName: 'Ezra' };

// Assign myObject to $this['name']. Now $this['name'] and name both point to the same reference.
$this['name'] = name;

// Change the value in the object pointed-to by name
name.firstName = 'Bob'

console.log($this['name'].firstName); // <- This will output 'Bob'
```